# How to add attributes to log method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, attributes

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70918769/1513027) shows one way to add the method name and line number where a log method is called from using attributes.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#2155-caller-info-attributes) gives more documentation on how it works.

But this would be most useful on getting an exception. I don't see how to get that to work.

The ILogger interface requires us to implement the log method with these parameters

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter) {
```

If I add the optional parameters at the end, then it says we are not implementing the interface.

Alternately, I could add it to the method we call when we get an exception

```
  public static void LogError(this ILogger logger, Exception? exception, string? message, params object?[] args);
```

but then we get an 'ambiguous method' error at compile.

What is the recommended approach to adding these optional parameters?

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a Extension method，you don't have to implement interface,just create a static class and write your method inside it,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

For example,I tried as below:

```
static class LogExtension
    {
        
        public static void LogError(this ILogger logger, string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = null, [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0,params object[] args)
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"In function {memberName} ({filePath}:{line}): {message}");
        }
        
    }
```

In controller:

```
_logger.LogError("Errormessage");
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You should not use string interpolation for messages. `logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "In function {memberName} ({filePath}:{line}): {message}", memberName, filePath, line, message);`